# Finding all $a$ for which $f$ is a characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory

Find all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the following function is a characteristic function
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1 + a|x|, & |x| \leq 1\\
1 + a, & |x| > 1
\end{cases}
$$

Now, I wanted to try Polya's criterion first. $f$ is even and $f(0)=1$. The only way for $f$ to have $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$ is when we set up $a = -1$. Then $f^{''}(x) \geq 0$ for $x\in [0, \infty)$. Thus $f$ satisfies Polya's criterion.

This is only one $a$ though! I also found out somewhere that if $f$ is constant then it is a characteristic function too which seem to help when $a = 0$.

For $a > 0$ $f(t) > 1$ for some $t$ which breaks $|\varphi(t)| \leq 1$ requirement of characteristic functions. So $a$ can't be positive. For $a < -2$ similar argument works.

What should I do next? Using Bochner's criteria seems a little harsh - I have no idea how to prove that $f$ is positive definite.

Comment: Convex combinations of characteristic functions are also characteristic functions.

Comment: @kimchilover That is true. Would you give me a bigger hint? Where do you see a convex combination here? For now I need to check all $a \in [-2,-1) \cup (-1, 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_a(x)=1+a\min(|x|,1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. The original question is, for which $a$ is $f_a$ the characteristic function of a probability law?  The OP noted that the for the cases $a=0$ and $a=-1$ the answer is *yes*, and that for all such $a$ the inequality $|a+1|\le1$ must hold.  D.k.o.'s answer is that by convexity, the answer is *yes* for the closed interval $[-1,0]$.  As the OP already noted, this leaves the question open for $a\in[-2,-1)$; he conjectured that these cases might be covered by Bochner's theorem.

Bochner's theorem tells us that $f_a$ is a characteristic function then all matrices of form $M=(f_a(x_i-x_j))$ must be p.s.d.
Consider the matrix resulting from $x_1=1, x_2=2,\ldots x_n=n$.
All the diagonal entries of $M$ are equal to $1$ and all off diagonal entries are equal to $1+a$.  Hence the sum of the entries of $M$ is equal to $n+n(n-1)(1+a)$.  But this sum must be non-negative, because it is also equal to $v'Mv$ where all the entries of $v$ are $1$.  Hence $n+(n-1)(1+a)\ge0$, for all $n>1$. This rules out $a<-1$.  That is, the set of $a$ for which $f_a$ is a characteristic function is exactly $[-1,0]$.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi_1(t)\equiv 1$ is the characteristic function of $\delta_0$ and $\varphi_2(t)=(1-|t|)1_{[-1,1]}(t)$ is the characteristic function of the distribution with density $g(x)=(1-\cos(x))/(\pi x^2)$. Then
$$
a\varphi_1+(1-a)\varphi_2
$$
is also a characteristic function for $a\in[0,1]$.